# Unable to identify chip on a fan module

Tags: transistors, identification

I know this is perhaps a silly question, but I looked everywhere.

I have a mean:IT 5PM case that has a fan PWM module. It looks like this:

[image: Fan Hub Module]

I accidently touched two wires to ground, burning this chip, which I can't read bcause its broken:

[image]

This broken chip is right behind this 470 inductor:

[image]

I am comfortable soldering, but I need to know what is broken to replace it. I'd really appreciate any lead on that.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  (1) The poor guy is called Q1 and Q is usually a transistor, and usually a bipolar, not mosfet transistor. (2) R1 102 is likely a biasing resistor for Q1. (3) Usually you can replace any NPN/PNP BJT by any other commonly used, dirt cheap, small signal NPN/PNP BJT, such as CS9012/CS9013 etc.   (4) Of course you don't need to find a SMD, through hole ones can do.  (5)  The three soldering pad for the SMD chip gives you a hint of the terminals, say the top pad is what, the lower two pads are what etc.

Comment: Looks like half of a SOT-23 (would that be a SOT-11.5?) I don't think there is enough left to ID. But I am guessing it is something like a BSS138. Since it is a SOT-23 and it says Q1 on the PCB I am sure it is some type of transistor.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree with tlfong01 that Q is usually BJT. I use Q for all transistors, whether MOSFET or BJT. Some people use M1 etc for MOSFET's but most of the schematics I have seen use Q.

Comment: If the seller has chat you could try sending them a picture and saying "what transistor is this... I want to replace it." Maybe they will tell you.

Comment: You might make a narrower guess if you google some DC PWM fan schematic, eg: https://www.electroschematics.com/4-wire-pc-fan/

Comment: (5) Since you don't have much more to lose, you might like to make some WordLe like guess. eg (a) Check if any of the three solder pads is shorted to ground, If yes, then it is likely that it is a NPN BJT emitter. (b) Then short this ground pad with any of the two pads, and see if the [12V powered on] fan turns.  (c) If the fans turns, congratulation, you found the collector! :)

Comment: I just bought the one provided by Tony in the answer. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid future finger trouble , you might be better off to replace the board.  https://www.ebay.ca/itm/134012376878?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=706-53473-19255-0&campid=5338722076&customid=&toolid=10050&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAAAkK1J5mUzlDzUfbxgANYVvit3a9%2F5MJWE5RCewBDfuOqDj7dTdGorVbBvREn2EW%2FcAuC1qG79DN8%2Fbad4CMkwnHvAEHEnt9w5CDr%2FxGnXRsh%2Fjaz8NIGigukq%2BUeZv7MRrZb%2Bb5eoMXXEzbzOjw06P7fjOgPqaindAV9HzTY6E0EuPm4HvuwrwqU62Kc3AOsY5w%3D%3D

Then you can try to learn by trial N error without risk in replacing the destroyed parts, but meanwhile be back up and running cool with your 7 fans

Comment: That's even better! Thanks a lot @Tony!